# "Peer not authenticated" when trying to add a form

Tags: ssl, orbeon

I have just installed Orbeon 3.9 CE on a WebSphere WAS 7.0 environment all was looking well but when I tried to add a form I got and error sating "peer not authenticated".
I turned on debugging in the log4j.xml file and this is what I got out of it:

`2011-05-27 16:34:13,051 ERROR ProcessorService  - Exception at oxf:/apps/fr/components/components.xsl (executing XSLT transformation)
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.ibm.jsse2.fc.getPeerCertificates(fc.java:46)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:390)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:488)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.connectSocket(SchemeSocketFactoryAdaptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:562)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.resources.handler.HTTPURLConnection.connect(HTTPURLConnection.java:219)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.util.Connection.connect(Connection.java:494)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.util.Connection.open(Connection.java:94)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator$URLResourceHandler.openConnection(URLGenerator.java:817)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator$URLResourceHandler.getResourceMediaType(URLGenerator.java:770)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.generator.URLGenerator$1.readImpl(URLGenerator.java:420)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:263)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:406)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readInputAsSAX(ProcessorImpl.java:260)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.TeeProcessor$TeeProcessorOutputImpl.readImpl(TeeProcessor.java:89)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl$TopLevelOutputFilter.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:263)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.impl.ProcessorOutputImpl.read(ProcessorOutputImpl.java:406)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readInputAsSAX(ProcessorImpl.java:260)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readInputAsTinyTree(ProcessorImpl.java:286)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl$3.read(ProcessorImpl.java:315)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readCacheInputAsObject(ProcessorImpl.java:365)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readCacheInputAsObject(ProcessorImpl.java:330)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.processor.ProcessorImpl.readCacheInputAsTinyTree(ProcessorImpl.java:313)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an error that would happen if you use HTTPS with an invalid certificate (such as a self-signed certificate). If this is what you are doing, you can either:

- Add the your certificate to your VM trust store. (I'll let you lookup how to do this on WebSphere.)
- Use HTTP instead of HTTPS, at least during development where you don't have a valid certificate.
- Get a real certificate, for instance from [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/) which issues class 1 certificate for free.

Comment: Thanks I will look in to this! I found out that if I connected the application to server1 which is the deployment manager server in this case, everything started to work, the client connection to server1 was http, not https, however when I tried to connect to the WebSphere_Portal instance in the same installation the problem was still there, no matter weather I used http or https. So the problem is related to the WebSphere_Portal instance. I have tried with classloade parent first /last to see if this had any relation but to no avail.

Comment: I found out that if I connected the application to server1 which is the deployment manager server in this case, everything started to work, the client connection to server1 was http, not https, I I tried using the HTTPS port I got the problem but when I tried to connect to the WebSphere_Portal instance in the same installation the problem was still there, no matter weather I used http or https. So the problem is related to the WebSphere_Portal instance. I will try using a valid SSL cert this week since I  indeed used a self certified certificate. Again, major thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: Sounds good, and thank you for the update. You'll let us know how it works out with a "real" certificate.